# Time reversal operator symmetry of dirac lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, time-reversal-symmetry, dirac-matrices

I want to prove time reversal symmetry of Dirac Lagrangian, I have some problems with calculations. I start with
\begin{eqnarray}
T\psi  T = U \psi
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
T\bar{\psi  }  T =  \psi^\dagger U^\dagger\gamma_0
\end{eqnarray} 
and I take   time reversal transformation of the first part of Dirac Lagrangian

\begin{eqnarray}
T\bar{\psi  } \gamma_aD^a\psi T = {\psi  }^\dagger U^\dagger\gamma_0 \gamma_aUD_a\psi  
\end{eqnarray}
I find, in order to parity invariant of the last part of Dirac Lagrangian 
\begin{eqnarray}
     U^\dagger\gamma_a U = \gamma^a 
 \end{eqnarray} 
this relation must satisfy.
But it is not true for the part

\begin{eqnarray}
T\bar{\psi  }  \psi T = {\psi  }^\dagger U^\dagger\gamma_0 U \psi  
\end{eqnarray}
 from here I find 
 \begin{eqnarray}
   U^\dagger\gamma_0 U  =   \gamma_0
\end{eqnarray}

This is not consistent  with  $U^\dagger\gamma_a U = \gamma^a $ for my convention.
Here I used (-+++) metric and  $TV^aT =V_a$, $\bar{\psi}= \psi\gamma_0$.
Can you show me my fault.

Comment: In your third identity, did you consider the fact that $T$ is anti unitary? So that, if I am not wrong, in the right-hand side $\gamma_a^*$ should appear in place of $\gamma_a$, the star denoting the complex conjugation.

Comment: I used $T\gamma_a T = \gamma_a$ , that is, gamma matrices are not effect by the transformation, ist it correct?

Comment: If $T$ is anti unitary there is an effect! $T\gamma_aT= T T \gamma_a^* = I\gamma^*_a = \gamma_a^*$.

Comment: $\gamma_a^*$  or $\gamma_a^\dagger$? Can you give me some ref.

Comment: $\gamma^*_a$ because you have to deal separately with each *complex* coefficient of $\gamma_a$

Comment: $\psi_a$ an operators, $(\gamma \psi)_a = \gamma_{ab}\sum_b\psi_b$. So $T\psi_aT = T \sum_b \gamma_{ab} \psi_bT = \sum_b T\gamma_{ab}\psi_bT= \sum_b \gamma_{ab}^* T\psi_bT$...

Comment: I do not have references now... however it is trivial.

Comment: The form of the matrix $U$ depends on your conventions on the choice of the rep of the $\gamma_a$ and takes all these constraints into account.

Comment: Can we say U also anti-unitary or $U^\dagger U=-1$

Comment: I do not remember, sorry, I am home now, I cannot check. I think that in Landau-Lifschitz' textbook on quantum relativistic theory there is a detailed (perhaps nowadays a bit confused) discussion with explicit formulas. Perhaps on Weinberg's textbook, first volume, something more modern appears.